# TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I have an array called test that stores information about a certain test. I am working on a comment functionality so that the user can comment a test. For now the user can only put one comment because the second is overwriting the first one. I now want to add a object in the array "comments" each time a comment is inputed.

```
var test = [{
        id: 0,
        test_id: "Password test",
        pass: 1,
        fail: 5,
        time: 0.03,
        pass_fail: 20,
        comments : [
            {comment : "", commentuser : "" },
        ]
    }
```

I use the push() function in order to do that :

```
app.post('/test/:id/comment', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    console.log("User Name : " + req.body.name);
    console.log("User Comment: " + req.body.comment);
    if (req.body.name && req.body.comment) {
        console.log('Your comment was posted !');
        res.sendFile(__dirname + '/HTML/comment-success.html');
        //test[req.params.id].comment = req.body.comment ;
        //test[req.params.id].commentuser = req.body.name ;
        var input = test[req.params.id].comments.comment;
        input.push(req.body.comment);
```

However I get the following error :
*TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined*. 
Thanks in advance for your help.
Cheers

Comment: That’s because `test[req.params.id]` returns undefined in your scenario. What is `req.params.id`? Remember that `test` is an **array** of objects so the bracket notation indicates you’re selecting based on array index—which I suspect you’ve misused. You might be looking for `test.find()` where an ID has to match your given ID?

Comment: hey! I am just wondering whether you've solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```js
if (req.body.name && req.body.comment) {
  console.log('Your comment was posted !');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/HTML/comment-success.html');
  //test[req.params.id].comment = req.body.comment ;
  //test[req.params.id].commentuser = req.body.name ;
  test[req.params.id].comments.push({
    comment: req.body.comment,
    commentuser: req.body.name
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second to last line you assign a string to input before using it as a array. At the time you try and push, input is not longer of type array.

Remember that comments is an array too so you could take out the .comment and make input an array of comments.

Answer (score 0):

There are some actions you can do to improve your code:

- try to check whether `req.params.id` exists
- `test[req.params.id].comments.comment` is not array, but `string`
- change name of variables from `input` to `comments`(`comment**s**` means many, so it could be array for others who will read code)

So the code should look like this

```
if (req && req.params &&  req.params.id) {
   // the other code is omitted for the brevity
   let comments = test[req.params.id].comments;
   comments.push(req.body.comment);
}
```